# Regex perl match delimited LaTeX text

Tags: regex, perl, text

I'm reading a .tex file and replacing according to a pattern for save in another .tex file. My left delimiter is

```
\ket{
```

and the right delimiter is

```
}
```

The regex `\\ket\{(.+)\}` can match

```
\ket{0}
```

but with complex lines such as

```
$\ket{\bfG \bfP^L_{2ex}}$, and the real space, $\ket{\bfP^L_{2ex}}$
```

it matches the entire text

```
\bfG \bfP^L_{2ex}}$, and the real space, $\ket{\bfP^L_{2ex}
```

Modifying the regex to

```
\\ket{([^{}]*|[^}])*}{1,2}
```

I can detect the mentioned complex line, but in cases such as

```
reciprocal lattice, $\ket{\bfG \bfP^L_{2ex}{3}{2}}$, and the real space, $\ket{\bfP^L_{2ex}}$
```

that doesn't work. How can I solve this? What algorithms/topics/books/tutorial must I read to solve problems like this?

Comment: Step 1: Stop using [regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Examples

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to reach for a tool for handling the (complex) problem of *balanced/nested delimiters*, instead of attempting to parse it by hand. Perhaps first look at the core [Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) or [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2017060201/lib/Regexp/Common.pm).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46121634/4653379) for an example of their use, that also comes very close to what you need.

---

In this case you may evade the problem, by making use of a specific property of your string.

If this formula is always inline, that is between `$...$`, then those `$`'s solve the problem

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $line = q( 
   $\ket{\bfG \bfP^L_{2ex}}$, and the real space, $\ket{\bfP^L_{2ex}}$ 
);

my @kets = $line =~ m| \$\\ket{ (.+?) }\s*\$ |gx;

say for @kets;
```

This prints

```
\bfG \bfP^L_{2ex}
\bfP^L_{2ex}
```

This is easy since the text you need is simply between the literal `$\ket{` and the first next `}$`; there is no issue of what's inside, so there is no problem with nested delimiters.

The `.+?` matches all characters up to the following pattern, here `}$` (with optional spaces, `\s*`, just in case). The `$` and `\` need be escaped. The `|x` modifier allows spaces for readability.