# Matching text not enclosed by parenthesis

Tags: perl, parentheses

I am still learning Perl, so apologies if this is an obvious question.
Is there a way to match text that is NOT enclosed by parenthesis?
For example, searching for foo would match the second line only.

```
(bar foo bar)
bar foo (
bar foo 
   (bar) (foo)
)
```

Comment: are you using negative lookahead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very far from "obvious"; on the contrary.  There is no direct way to say "don't match" for a complex pattern (there is good support at a character level, with `[^a]`, `\S` etc).  Regex is firstly about matching things, not about not-matching them.

One approach is to match those (possibly nested) delimiters and get everything other than that.

A good tool for finding nested delimiters is the core module [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html). As it matches it can also give us the substring before the match and the rest of the string after the match.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);

my $text = <<'END';
(bar foo bar)
bar foo (
bar foo 
   (bar) (foo)
   )
END

my ($match, $before);
my $remainder = $text;
while (1) {
    ($match, $remainder, $before) = extract_bracketed($remainder, '(', '[^(]*');
    print $before // $remainder;
    last if not defined $match; 
}
```

The `extract_bracketed` returns the match, the remainder substring (`$remainder`), and the substring before the match (`$before`); so we keep matching in the remainder.

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46121634/4653379), where there are more details and another way, using [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2017060201/lib/Regexp/Common.pm).

Comment: I didn't know about this module. Thanks! Though, I am finding it difficult to find the line number when matching inside `$text` or `$lead`. One way could be to count the number of newline characters in `$match`. But is there a better way?

Comment: @Tohiko  Welcome.  You mean to find what char/line in the source is found? Counting `\n` in the `$lead` (or `$text`, as it's being depleted) won't inform what line it is in the source.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @Tohiko Note that I changed `$lead` to `$before` and `$text` to `$remainder`

Comment: @Tohiko  I didn't find a better way than counting.  It is not tested well (works on _this_ example) and there are probably all kinds of cases for which it won't, but here is the idea. I add `$line_cnt=1` and after `print ...` add the line `$line_cnt += () = ($before =~ /\n/g)  if $before;`. The module may provide a better way but it's been a while since I read the whole page carefully. Will update if I find it

Comment: @Tohiko Another feature is `$@->{pos}`, see [Diagnostics](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html#DIAGNOSTICS).  But in this case, because of recursive processing, I still have to count lines.

Answer (score 5):

Regex patterns have an implicit leading `\G(?s:.)*?` ("skip characters until a match is found"). The following expands that definition to consider nested parens to be a character to skip.

```
while (
   $string =~ m{
      \G (?&MEGA_DOT)*?

      ( foo )

      (?(DEFINE)
         (?<MEGA_DOT> [^()] | \( (?&MEGA_DOT)*+ \) )
      )
   }xg
) {
   say "Found a match at pos $-[1].";
}
```

Comment: Admirable! But I reckon this is a reason why people get frightened when they scent Perl... ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck, Actually, it's amazing how simple and structured Perl made this.

Comment: As a beginner I couldn't understand this hence kindly provide a detailed methodology to learn.

Comment: I second @ssr1012 request.

Comment: I already explained the methodology in the answer. The rest is documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), but it's either elementary regex, or obvious (`(&NAME)` matches the pattern defined by `(?<NAME> ... )`).