# perl balanced constructs

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

Given the following input:

```
$ cat liltester
      if ((ret = utMemAlloc(
                   pManeuverObj->util.hMemory,
                   1,
                   (usTxtLen + 1),
                   (void **)&pMnvr->Context.pDestinationString
                 )) < 0)
```

The following produces the expected output (it strips out everything outside the outer parens)

```
$ perl -0 -ne 'print $1 if /((?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)))/g' liltester
```

I grabbed that from https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html , by the way.  However, it's been modified to 1) capture, and have the "balanced" portion be inside a non-capturing group.  The idea being I can do this

```
$ perl -0 -ne 'print $1 if /(utMemAlloc(?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)))/g' liltester
```

without modifying `(` being considered as my opening paren.  (As obviously trying to match `utMemAlloc(` with `)` is not going to work well.)

However, the output is a blank line.  Expected output is:

```
utMemAlloc(
                   pManeuverObj->util.hMemory,
                   1,
                   (usTxtLen + 1),
                   (void **)&pMnvr->Context.pDestinationString
                 )
```

My end goal, for what it's worth, is to find instances of `utMemAlloc` that use `pDestinationString`in the parameter list.

The following produces the expected output, by the way, but I'd prefer to avoid it for several reasons (one of which is that `$RE{balanced}` seems to blow up perl for an entire shell instance whenever I use it wrong):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -0 -ne 'print $1 if /(utMemAlloc$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'"'"'()'"'"'})/g' liltester
```

**Optional Reading**

The other reason I prefer to avoid `Regexp::Common` is that I often use perl in a mingw terminal provided by a git UI..Basically to avoid having to push code through git to a linux box.  The *actual* code I ended up with (thanks to the current answer) is:

```
$ git grep -l 'pDestinationString' | 
xargs perl -0 -lne 'print for /(utMemAlloc\s*(\((?>[^()]|(?-1))*\)))/g' | 
perl -0 -ne 'print "$_\n\n\n" if /utMemAlloc[\s\S]*pDestinationString/'
```

The 2nd test for utMemAlloc was necessary because there are two capture groups in the first expression, and when I tried to make the inner one a non-capturing group, the whole expression stopped working again.  This works, but it's damn ugly.

Comment: Did you consider the core [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html)? It won't blow up anything. See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46121634/4653379)

Comment: @zdim - I'll check it out next time.  I'm not sure learning this syntax is worthwhile.  (also see my edit at the bottom of my question)

Comment: @zdim - sorry, by "this", I mean the syntax *I'm* trying to use, not what you're suggesting.

Comment: Aaand, I found the memory error.  All hail perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$^R` you recurse to the beginning of the whole pattern, apparently this is not what you want.
If you recurse to the paren character you will get the desired result:

`perl -0 -ne 'print $1 if /(utMemAlloc(\((?>[^()]|(?-1))*\)))/g' liltester`

---

```
utMemAlloc(
               pManeuverObj->util.hMemory,
               1,
               (usTxtLen + 1),
               (void **)&pMnvr->Context.pDestinationString
             )
```

Comment: This answers my question.  Curious if you have any thoughts on the edit (bottom).  Also wondering why this stops working if I change `utMemAlloc(` to `utMemAlloc(?:` (non-capturing)

Comment: Also, blessings be upon you `curl -sN https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Psalms-23-4/ | perl -0 -ne 'print $1 if /(<p class='"'"'pspace'"'"'>.*?<\/p>)/' | perl -lpe 's/\<.*?\>//g; s/\b\d?\K(the lord|thou\b|he\b)/Perl/gi; s/thy/Perl'"'"'s/gi; s/his/its/gi; s/(\d)/\n$1 /g'`

Comment: @zzxyz, thanks for the blessing, very funny. As to the update, you've probably already known that `(?-1)` refers to the latest capturing subgroup, and with `(?:` you make the subgroup non-capturing.

Comment: @wolkrevokcats - I actually didn't know about `(?-1)`..I couldn't find any reference material that mentioned it.  I finally started just playing with it to figure out it referred to capture groups, which is why using a non-capturing group doesn't work.

Comment: Finding related docs is as easy as running `perldoc perlre` and searching for `?R`. You can even find it through the table of contents -  `perldoc toc`.

Comment: Yeah, I really need to remember that perldoc is usually better than google for finding...perl documentation :)