# perl remove string block from file and save to file

Tags: string, perl, block

I have a file that looks like this:

```
string 1 {
    abc { session 1 }
    fairPrice {
            ID LU0432618274456
            Source 4
            service xyz
    }
}
string 2 {
    abc { session 23 }
    fairPrice {
            ID LU036524565456171
            Source 4
            service tzu 
    }
}
```

My program should read in the file with a search-parameter given (for example "string 1") and search the complete block until "}" and remove that part from the file. Can someone assist on that...I have some code so far but how can I do the removal and saving to the same file again?

```
my $fh = IO::File->new( "$fname", "r" ) or die ( "ERROR: Strategy file      \"$fname\" not found." );
while($line=<$fh>)
{
    if ($line =~ /^\s*string 1\s*\w+\s*\{\s*$/) {
            $inside_json_msg = 1;
            $msg_json .= $line;
    }
    else {
            if ($inside_json_msg)
            {
               if ($line =~ m/^\}\s*$/) {

                 $msg_json.= $line if defined($line);
                 $inside_json_msg = 0;
               } else {
                 $msg_json .= $line;
               }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars)

Comment: Wait, your code mentions JSON. Is the data actually JSON? If so, there are libraries you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code mentions JSON, but your data isn't JSON. If it is JSON and you've just transcribed it badly, then please use [a JSON library](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

But if your data isn't JSON, then something like this will do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $match = shift or die "I need a string to match\n";

while (<DATA>) {
  # If this is the start of a block we want to remove...
  if (/^\s*$match\s+{/) {
    # Set $braces to 1 (or 0 if the block closes on this line)
    my $braces = /}/ ? 0 : 1;
    # While $braces is non-zero
    while ($braces) {
      # Read the next line of the file
      $_ = <DATA>;
      # Increment or decrement $braces as appropriate
      $braces-- if /}/;
      $braces++ if /{/;
    }
  } else {
    # Otherwise, just print the line
    print;
  }
}

__DATA__
string 1 {
    abc { session 1 }
    fairPrice {
            ID LU0432618274456
            Source 4
            service xyz
    }
}
string 2 {
    abc { session 23 }
    fairPrice {
            ID LU036524565456171
            Source 4
            service tzu 
    }
}
```

Currently, this just prints the output to the console. And I use the `DATA` filehandle for easier testing. Switching to use real filehandles is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

**Update:** I decided that I didn't like all the incrementing and decrementing of `$braces` using regex matches. So here's another (improved?) version that uses `y/.../.../` to count the occurrences of opening and closing braces in the line. It's possible that this version might be slightly less readable (the syntax highlighter certainly thinks so).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $match = shift or die "I need a string to match\n";

while (<DATA>) {
  if (/^\s*$match\s+{/) {
    my $braces = y/{// - y/}//;
    while ($braces) {
      $_ = <DATA>;
      $braces -= y/}//;
      $braces += y/{//;
    }
  } else {
    print;
  }
}

__DATA__
string 1 {
    abc { session 1 }
    fairPrice {
            ID LU0432618274456
            Source 4
            service xyz
    }
}
string 2 {
    abc { session 23 }
    fairPrice {
            ID LU036524565456171
            Source 4
            service tzu 
    }
}
```

**Update 2:** Ok, I originally said that dealing with real filehandles would be left as an exercise for the reader. But here's a version that does that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $match = shift or die "I need a string to match\n";

open my $fh, '+<', 'data' or die $!;

# Read all the data from the file
my @data = <$fh>;

# Empty the file
seek $fh, 0, 0;
truncate $fh, 0;

my $x = 0;
while ($x <= $#data) {
  $_ = $data[$x++];
  if (/^\s*$match\s+{/) {
    my $braces = y/{// - y/}//;
    while ($braces) {
      $_ = $data[$x++];
      $braces -= y/}//;
      $braces += y/{//;
    }
  } else {
    print $fh $_;
  }
}
```

Currently, I've hard-coded the filename to be `data`. I hope it's obvious how to fix that.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the hints I'd prefer the 1st way...but any idea on how to remove and print to the exact same file that I am reading from ? Thanks and regards

Comment: actually your code just prints the whole file but i wanted to have everything from string 1 down to the last closing brace removed...so it should just print everything from string 2 onwards....

Comment: *actually your code just prints the whole file* It only does that if you call it with a string that isn't the name of a block in the file. How did you call it? *i wanted to have everything from string 1 down to the last closing brace removed* That's exactly what it does if you call it correctly.

Comment: @Unsal: *any idea on how to remove and print to the exact same file that I am reading from ?* Yes. See my latest update.

Comment: @Unsal: How are you calling it?

Comment: like this: ./script_name [match] ['data']

Comment: actually this solves my problem, it may not be the cleanest way but it works:

Comment: HI Dave, one question: What if I wanted to remove more than 2 string blocks? Any hint on that? I tried to wrap it into a foreach loop but it will not work like that...

Comment: @Unsal: My code as it currently is will remove multiple blocks that match the same search criteria. If you want to add a new requirement to your question, then the best approach is to ask a new question. My answer answers the question that you asked.

Comment: thanks dave, i actually solved the problem using a lexical in my while loop

Answer (score 2):

Can use [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) to break the text into blocks delimited by `{}`, in a way that also keeps the text preceding and following the blocks.

In that list drop the element with the specific skip-pattern (`string 1` here) and its following block and retain everything else. Then overwrite the source file with that.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Path::Tiny;
use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed extract_multiple);

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";  #/
my $text = path($file)->slurp;

# returns: 'string 1', BLOCK, 'string 2', BLOCK (may have spaces/newlines)
my @elems = extract_multiple( 
    $text, [ sub { extract_bracketed($text, '{}') } ]
); 

my $skip_phrase = 'string 1';    
my (@text_keep, $skip);

for (@elems) {
    if (/$skip_phrase/) { 
        $skip = 1;
        next;
    }   
    elsif ($skip) {
        $skip = 0;
        next
    }

    push @text_keep, $_;
}

print for @text_keep;

# Overwrite source; uncomment when tested
#open my $fh_out, '>', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";  
#print $fh_out $_ for @text_keep;
```

Tested with files with more text and blocks, both before and after the one to drop.

Another tool that can be used to extract delimited chunks is in [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common), see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46121634/4653379).

Answer (score 1):

I would use proper **json** as format and **jq** as processor for that format. Rewriting a hack in perl does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [`Regexp::Grammars`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use Regexp::Grammars;
{
    my ($block_name, $block_num) = @ARGV;
    my $parser = qr!
        <nocontext:> 
        <blocks>
        <rule: blocks> <[block]>+ 
        <rule: block> <block_name> <block_num> <braced_item>
        <token: block_name> \w+
        <token: block_num> \d+
        <rule: braced_item>   \{  (?: <escape> | <braced_item> | [^{}] )*  \}
        <token: escape> \\ .
    !xms;

    my $data = read_file('cfg.txt');
    if ($data =~ $parser) {
        print_blocks( $/{blocks}{block}, $block_name, $block_num );
    }
    else {
        warn "No match";
    }
}

sub print_blocks {
    my ( $blocks, $block_name, $block_num ) = @_;

    for my $block (@$blocks) {
        next if ($block->{block_name} eq $block_name)
          && ($block->{block_num} == $block_num);
        say $block->{block_name}, " ", $block->{block_num},
          " ", $block->{braced_item}{braced_item};
    }
}

sub read_file {
    my ( $fn ) = @_;

    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh;
    return $str;
}
```